# Pasar variable PHP a otro PHP por medio de ajax Y recargar una parte del documento

Tags: php, ajax

Al momento de hacer click en una parte de la pagina debo pasar un id a otro php pero lo hago por medio de ajax, el php que recibe la variable hace una tabla por medio de los datos que recibió y quiero que ese php se muestre en un "div" pero no logro pasar la variable

aqui dejo el codigo que estoy usando

```
function detalleVenta(idVenta){
    cadena="id=" + idVenta 
    $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   data:cadena,
   url:"detalleVenta.php",
   success:function(r){  
      if(r==true){
        $("#contenedorPrincipal").load('detalleVenta.php');
      }else{
        $("#contenedorPrincipal").load('detalleVenta.php');
      }
     }
    });
}
```

aqui el PHP "detalleVenta" que recibe la variable y pinta la tabla

```
<?php


$idVenta=$_POST["id"];


require_once('php/bdConexion.php');
$sql= "select p.DIRECCION_IMAGEN, p.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, p.PRECIO_PRODUCTO, d.PIEZAS
from ventas as v, DETALLE_VENTA as d, PRODUCTOS as p
where v.ID_VENTA=D.ID_VENTA and d.ID_PRODUCTO=p.ID_PRODUCTO and v.ID_VENTA='$idVenta'
";  
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$consulta=sqlsrv_query($conexion,$sql, $params,$options);
echo '<script>';
echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $idVenta ) .')';
echo '</script>';


?>
<div class="container">
    <button id="regresarAdministrador" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Regresar al panel principal</button>
</div>


<br>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Imagen producto</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre producto</th>
      <th scope="col">costo</th>
      <th scope="col">Piezas</th>
      <th scope="col">Importe</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $consulta, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {

 ?>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo $row[0];?></th>
      <td><?php ?></td>
      <td>Si</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

El problema aqui es que cuando mando a imprimir a consola la variable $idVenta, no me muestra nada y me dice que es nula

Comment: Porque no usas variables de sesión?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inténtalo de esta manera, no hace falta crear una variable y concatenar un string con otra variable, solo basta poner en la data la clave y el valor que vas a obtener en PHP, de esta manera `data:{id: idVenta }` en PHP lo obtienes `$_POST['id'];`.

```js
function detalleVenta(idVenta){
    //cadena="id=" + idVenta 
    $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   data:{id: idVenta },
   url:"detalleVenta.php",
   success:function(r){  
      if(r==true){
        $("#contenedorPrincipal").load('detalleVenta.php');
      }else{
        $("#contenedorPrincipal").load('detalleVenta.php');
      }
     }
    });
}
```